# Table view not appearing the same way in iOS7 as it did in iOS6

Tags: uitableview, ios7

The relevant part of the code is in - `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
   cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",result.level]]];
} else {
   cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",indexPath.row+OFFSETTOFIRSTROW]]];
}
cell.backgroundView.alpha = 0.5;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
if (totalPieces) {
   cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.5 blue:0.1 alpha:1.0];
   cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   if (indexPath.row == 0) {
      cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.5 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
      cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
      cell.backgroundView.alpha = 1.0;
   }
   cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);
} else {
   cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   cell.textLabel.shadowColor = nil;
}
```

Essentially, each row of the table has its own background image. This appears correctly in iOS6. But in iOS7, what happens is that the image is covered by what appears to be the background color. That is, until the user scrolls the table. When the user scrolls the table, it displays properly. What's making it behave differently upon first presentation? What should I do to fix it?

The intended result is a background color of dark grey covering the whole cell. Above that is the background image, which has some transparency, through which the background color should show. Above that is the text, which has a transparent background so the image/cell background shows through.

Unless I hear something else, I suppose what I'll do is to stack two images instead of using the cell background.

Answer (score 1):

First clear the background view of cell by setting it to nil. Then set a custom view

```
[cell setBackgroundView: nil];
UIView* bview = [[UIView alloc] init];
bview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:@"your image"];
[cell setBackgroundView:bview];
```

This worked for me.. Hope it will work for you too.. :-) Best of luck..

Comment: Please notice that my image has transparency. The transparent portion needs to reveal what I've been calling the background color. I am not simply replacing the background color with an image, which is what your code does.

Comment: you want to set a background colour and background image both ??? then go for a custom cell

Comment: That's another option, sure. But simply setting the background color and background image worked just fine in iOS6. Part of what I was trying to get at was what the underlying difference is. I suppose it's just an accident that it worked in iOS6, since a plain reading of the documentation looks like an image and a background color aren't meant to go together.

Comment: As far as I know in tableview cell view you can not set background colour and image simultaneously unless you creating a custom cell. And the cell's image view size is also predefined..

Comment: That is not clear from the documentation. In fact, I would suggest the opposite. The background color is set using a property of the superclass, UIView. The background view is a property of the table view cell class. I see nothing that suggests they are mutually exclusive. They can both be used simultaneously. The only issue is which is on top. The docs do say the background view is put behind all other views. To my mind, that didn't include the background color, which is not a view (unless it is specified as in your original answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is an intended change by Apple. To fix it change `cell.backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

Comment: Nope. That won't work. I just edited my post. The background is NOT supposed to be clear. It should show through the transparent part of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

OK. This solution works, although maybe there's a more efficient one.

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
   [backgroundView addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",result.level]]]];
   cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
} else {
   [backgroundView addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",indexPath.row+OFFSETTOFIRSTROW]]]];
   cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
}
```